# How to move all windows from the same application to the external monitor in OSX

Tags: macos, mac, osx-lion

This is a question in regards to OSX Lion 10.7

When I have all my lecture slides open in PowerPoint I move them all into the external display's desktop.
However if I put my laptop to sleep and return to it, all the PowerPoint slides have moved back to the MacBook's monitor (about 12 windows).

Is there any way to move all the windows of a specific app across to the external display? I know if you click on the app's icon in Mission Control you can move all the windows into another desktop, but when you move it across monitors it simply snaps back to it's original place.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The windows move to the MacBook's display when sleeping because you may disconnect the external monitor, and the system is trying to prevent you from losing access to them.

There's a third-party utility to work around this called [DisplayMaid](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/display-maid/id450063525).  I haven't tried it personally.